# Knockout text. Illustrator won't do full text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, outline

So I am trying to knock out the foreground object, in this case, it's text from the design. But it's not doing exactly what I want. 
I would like to do it creating outlines since I want to unite another object to this eventually. however, I am having a hard time, cause it seems to only knock out part of the text and I am not using a stroke as it is transparent now.

[Knockout issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egjm5sbt9a5ajzh/2019-03-16_09-51-38.gif?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: I think we need more information such as your layers' panel contents and the fill/stroke that is currently applied to any object - to help with troubleshooting. So, add those areas to your screen capture video?

Comment: Sure, the layers are pretty basic. And the fill and strok set up is at the end https://www.dropbox.com/s/frunae86d6qw93g/2019-03-16_10-14-45.gif?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a 9pt stroke applied to the white rectangle. It's causing the extra weight after you cut out the outlined words.
If that is your issue, just remove the stroke - to be sure you did it just set the stroke size to 0.

Comment: Ah, thanks I didn't know the stroke would push in the text when cutting it. I just set it to none. and that worked. Thought I was being smart doing it that way to align with the other box.

Comment: GDSE helps people around the globe, pass it on dude!